# Different classes as a package with Prisma to use them in multiple projects

Tags: node.js, npm, prisma

I was just wondering if it is somehow possible to provide multiple TypeScript classes as a package so that they can be used by multiple classes.

For example, I use the same class in three of my projects, and as soon as I change something in one project there, I inevitably have to copy the file to the other projects, and apply the changes from there as well, if they exist, which is more or less tedious.

Now I thought that I could create a private package, which contains these classes to consume them in the respective projects.

But now I have the question, is this possible with Prisma?
Let's assume I have a database management class, and a model from my Prisma schema is expected as a parameter, theoretically I would have to include my Prisma schema in the package, or am I seeing this wrong?

Unfortunately I didn't find any solutions on various other sites, so I have this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. using `private CDN` or `npm` package is a good choice for this kind of use case.
   follow [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-private-packages) link

2. You can definitely gather all your `classes` inside a single file and import it whenever you need it.
3. For prisma , `schema.prisma` , I guess you might need to write some code's in `Node js` in order to reade your `schema.prisma` file from your package and merge it with your local `schema.prisma` , because `datasource` is specific for each project. After that you can create a newly create `schema.prisma` file to `pull` , `push` or etc to your database

```js
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = "postgres://......"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and pointing out the options that are possible!